# fetching article from mysql db with slug url

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, slug

Im developing my own PHP Mysql site.

I used to fetch data by id like this : `mysite.com/articles.php?id=12`

now i want to change the url with slug:

`mysite.com/articles/google-search`

or

`mysite.com/articles.php?article=google-search`

**I dont want to use id and numbers.**

My table:

```
+----+---------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id | title         | article |   urlslug                          |
+----+---------------+---------+------------------------------------+
| 12 | google search | xxxxxxx |   google-search                    |
| 13 | bing yahoo    | xxxxxxx |   bing-yahoo                       |
| 14 | friendly seo  | xxxxxxx |   friendly-seo                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I used the below code to get data by id:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo ($row['title']);
echo ($row['article']);    }
```

I tried the above code by substituting urlslug it says `Invalid ID specified.`
I googled and even searched in stack questions i didnt get any help. Please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you echo `echo $_GET['id'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If url is like this `mysite.com/articles.php?article=google-search`
then instead of `id` get the `article` from url and change the condition to `urlslug` instead of id.

```
$slug = $_GET['article'];
$slug = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$slug);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `urlslug`='" . $slug. "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

 //Since  slug is unique you will get only 1 result so no need to loop

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 echo $row['title'];
 echo $row['article'];
```

Comment: slug must be unique. so you don't need to bother about number of articles.

Comment: bro in christ, im totally new to this. i tried in the way u suggested but it says invalid id specified

Comment: @dan Which means you have check the `id` some where in your application. php doesn't provide such a message `invalid id specified` so find that in your code.. which was not mentioned in your question. I think its a very small problem.

Comment: `invalid id specified` have you given such a message in any part of your code...???  please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96777/discussion-between-tintu-c-raju-and-dan).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ /articles.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite

```
example.com/articles/123
```

to

```
example.com/articles.php?id=123
```